# Service Bus connection always times out

Tags: azureservicebus

I have a function that is triggered by a ServiceBusTrigger and I have been testing it by using Service Bus Explorer to load up the message and trigger my function. This has worked fine but I am now trying to automate that process but the code I write for uploading a message to SB is timing out.

Endpoint class:

```
public class ServiceBusEndPoint
    {
        private readonly string _serviceBus;

        public ServiceBusEndPoint()
        {
            _serviceBus = TestContext.Parameters["serviceBus"];
            TestContext.Out.WriteLine($"Service bus {_serviceBus}");
        }

        public QueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName)
        {
            return new QueueClient(_serviceBus, queueName);
        }
    }
```

And using it like this:

```
var sbClient = _sbEndPoint.GetQueueClient(TestContext.Parameters["sbQueue"]);
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(validTestFile));
await sbClient.SendAsync(message);
```

and that is always timing out:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

So initially I was thinking firewall but ServiceBus Explorer has no problem uploading a file to the queue.

Can anyone explain why Service Bus Explorer is ok and this method cannot connect?

Answer (score 2):

ServiceBus Explorer is using NetMessaging, which can failover from AMQP to HTTPS. It also uses the old SDK where you're using the new SDK, which doesn't failover and by default uses AMQP. Try switching to connection over WebSockets

```
Endpoint=sb://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<policy>;
SharedAccessKey=<key>;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets
```

Also, check if the connection is still open before you send by validating [`IsClosedOrClosing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.cliententity.isclosedorclosing?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_ClientEntity_IsClosedOrClosing) property on the queue client.

Comment: I thought that was going to work but I am afraid it hasn't. I have added the transport type to my connection string and get the same message. I have checked the permissions I am connecting with and they are good. Nust be the firewall I am behind maybe.

Comment: You should be able to connect from behind a firewall as well. Have you tried your code in a different environment?